# How to add data in a dictionary in the same order of the list containing the keys in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a list

```
myList=['a' , 'b', 'c','d']
```

and a dictionary:

```
data={}
```

When i iterate over the list and append its data into the dictionary:

```
for i in myList:
    print i
    data[i]={'name':"jack",'date': "2015-10-01"}
print data
```

I assumed that the dictionary will be formed in the order of list as per the code, but when i print the dictionary and the i(from list):
list=>
    a
    b
    c
    d
dictionary=>

```
{'a': {'date':"2015-10-01",'name':"jack"}, 'c':  {'date':"2015-10-01",'name':"jack"}, 'b':  {'date':"2015-10-01",'name':"jack"}, 'd': {'date':"2015-10-01",'name':"jack"}}
```

May i know why does the result come in the unordered way. And how can i make the dictionary in the same order as of the list.

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict` no keeping order. You could use for that [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html). From docs:

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
>   methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

For your case:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict()

for i in myList:
    data[i] ={'name':"jack",'date': "2015-10-01"}


In [616]: data
Out[616]: 
OrderedDict([('a', {'date': '2015-10-01', 'name': 'jack'}),
             ('b', {'date': '2015-10-01', 'name': 'jack'}),
             ('c', {'date': '2015-10-01', 'name': 'jack'}),
             ('d', {'date': '2015-10-01', 'name': 'jack'})])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was great.

Comment: Thanx.that was gret. But may i know on what basis the order of dictionary is created is it the key or something else.

Comment: See `quotes` from docs in edited answer:   An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted